# Problema con la letra "ñ" en PostgreSQL - Express

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, express

Cuando uso INSERT y escribo una palabra con la letra "ñ", logro ver esa palabra normal en PostgreSQL. El problema es cuando hago una consulta con la librería `const { Pool } = require('pg')` y `const res = await pool.query(stmt, params)`, escribo `console.log()` para ver el resultado y me sale con este símbolo "¤", en vez de la "ñ".

Como menciono, el problema es cuando hago la consulta a través de `const { Pool } = require('pg')`, porque cuando escribo `SELECT * FROM tabla_1` directamente en PostgreSQL, sí me aparece la "ñ" normal.

Qué puede ser?

Comment: ¿Codificación de caracteres de la base de datos?

Comment: ¿No creo que el problema esté en la base de datos o sí? Como menciono, sí logro ver la "ñ" con SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no era `const { Pool } = require('pg')`. Todo lo que tenía que hacer, era crear la base de datos con la codificación, collate y ctype correctos.
(e.g. `CREATE DATABASE nombre_de_baseDatos WITH ENCODING 'WIN1252' LC_COLLATE='Spanish_Mexico.1252' LC_CTYPE='Spanish_Mexico.1252' TEMPLATE=template0;`)

Comment: Ya puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada -> click en check verde del costado :D